# notifyDataSetChanged() not working for Spinner's adapter

Tags: android, spinner, adapter, android-spinner, notifydatasetchanged

In my app, I have a spinner whose head view (the view returned from ArrayList.getView()) needs to be redrawn. I want to be able to call notifyDataSetChanged() to redraw the head view but getView() and getDropDownView() both aren't getting called, it seems like if the adpater is used for a spinner, notifyDataSetChanged() doesn't work correctly.

I am able to accomplish what I need by resetting the adapter for the spinner, but this causes other problems where the spinner item select listener is getting fired. Does anyone have tips on how to get a spinner to redraw it's header view?

Below is an example of what I mean by the spinner's "header view". The views that show planets Mercury to Neptune are the drop down views, and the top view that you click to open/close the spinner is the "header view".
[image]

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve? Do you want to change the title of a dialog when it's shown or the text of a selected item on spinner control ?

Comment: I want to redraw the header view for the spinner, which is what is returned from Adapter.getView(). notifyDataSetChanged() is not doing that for some reason.

Comment: still not able to get you, may be you can post some screenshots here.

Comment: @KunalK I added a screenshot for what I meant by header view. let me know if you need more details.